# Did four LED light bulbs break my light fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led

I have a bathroom light fixture with 4 light bulbs. Until yesterday, those light bulbs were the classic incandescent light bulbs from GE. That light fixture has been working for the last 7 years with those light bulbs.

I replaced the light bulbs with 4 Greenlite LED light bulbs (3000K, 9W). I turned off the light fixture. Replaced the light bulbs and turned it back on. The 4 LED light bulbs were turned on for half a second and then short circuited (it tripped the breaker). I removed the LED light bulbs and put back the GE incandescent light bulbs. Reset the breaker. Same results: the light bulbs turn on for half a second and then the breaker trips. I cannot use the light fixture anymore. I haven't tried the LED light bulbs in another light fixture.

What did I do wrong? What am I missing? Did the LED light bulbs broke the light fixture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you broke a socket or wire when replacing the lamps (bulbs). This could have happened with any lamp, it was not the fault of the LEDs.

Try to reset the breaker with no lamps in the fixture at all. Then put in one lamp at a time and try again each time.

Either way, I'd replace the fixture. If that is not possible financially I would remove the fixture and find the bad wire/socket and remove it.